# Add Google map or bing as base layer in ArcGIS api for android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, arcgis

I'm using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android to build my application. I want to add a Google map as the basemap. Is that possible? Can I use `ArcGISFeatureLayer` to add a Google map layer or other layer to my `MapView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`BingMapsLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/bing/BingMapsLayer.html) class to add a Bing Maps layer to the [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html). You'll need to obtain a Bing Maps key from Microsoft.

There's no direct interface for adding Google Maps to the `MapView`. But you could try extending [`TiledServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/TiledServiceLayer.html) if you must use Google Maps. Do a web search for ["extends TiledServiceLayer"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22extends+tiledservicelayer%22) for examples. [Here's an example that uses Google Maps](http://www.programering.com/q/MDO5kjMwATc.html), though I don't know if it works, and I don't know if it abides by Google's terms of service.

You should also consider the easier and no-cost options of ArcGIS Online basemaps (see [`ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.html)) and OpenStreetMap (see [`OpenStreetMapLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/osm/OpenStreetMapLayer.html)).

In any case, [`ArcGISFeatureLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISFeatureLayer.html) is not the right class to use for a tiled basemap. It's for feature services.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help.In fact I can not access to ArcGIS Online basemaps in my country.It remans OSM layers and Bing which I can use them,Do you have any example how to extend TiledServiceLayer to use google map?

Comment: I don't have a Google example, but I did a web search to find some examples. I edited my answer to include more information that should help you.